# Rundeck localization problems. Question symbols ????? instead of Russian letters in the Log Output section

Tags: rundeck

In Rundeck section "Log Output" I see question symbols instead of Russian letters in the text of log.

Where can I configure the correct display of Russian characters in the Log Output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to set UTF-8 as default encoding at the moment of start Rundeck, try adding `RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"` on the `rundeckd` file, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/system-properties.html#rpm-and-deb) (please do no edit the `profile` file directly). [Here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1619) you can see the same issue on GitHub, especially this [comment](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1619#issuecomment-169807329).

Comment: I added string RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to /etc/init.d/rundeckd , but after restarting the server, the situation has not changed. I even changed the /etc/rundeck/profile file contrary to the recommendation, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you try this https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1619#issuecomment-169807329? It's the same case?

Comment: Is there a way to see what the current encoding page is in Randeck ?

Comment: You can run `echo $LANG` on the command section (left menu).

Comment: echo $LANG gives: en_US.UTF-8
The results of the task execution are stored in directories: /var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/project_name/job/job_identificator/logsjob_Id.rdlog
Incorrectly encoded data is already being saved there.

And one more moment. If I give the command: 
echo "Тест шага"     result -> Request failed: undefined

Comment: I think that's not Rundeck related :\ maybe is something related to at OS level, could you try on another machine? (maybe a virtual machine)  https://imgur.com/70S106B (rdlog here: https://pastebin.com/QhBBm8sM).