# Remote options fail

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying to setup an option value, using cascading remote option strategy.
Parent option name: --serv
Parent option value: Administración de sistemas (note the ó)

*Child option

To get child option values, I use cascading options based on parent option value (--serv)

Remote URL value is: `file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_${option.--serv.value}-componentes.json`

When I choose "Administración de sistemas" value on --serv option, I got the following error:

`Exception: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 49: file:/scripts/path/conf/list_Administraci%F3n de Sistemas-componentes.json URL: file:/scripts/path/conf/list_Administraci%F3n de Sistemas-componentes.json`

I tried to "manually" encode ó character with, substituying ó with %f3, without any success. Indeed the blank space in filename represent the same problem

--- UPDATE ---
For better explanation, Here, I post options code

```
  - description: Indicar el servicio
    enforced: true
    label: Servicio
    name: --serv
    required: true
    value: Administración de Sistemas
    valuesUrl: file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_Servicio.json
  - description: Indica la operacion
    enforced: true
    label: Operacion
    name: --oper
    required: true
    value: Realizar petición
    valuesUrl: file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_Operacion.json
  - description: Componente
    enforced: true
    label: Componente de infraestructura
    name: --comp
    required: true
    value: ESPECIFICAR
    valuesUrl: file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_${option.--serv.value}-componentes.json
```

Note the Componente option and option value `valuesUrl: file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_${option.--serv.value}-componentes.json`

Now, `/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_Servicio.json` have the following content inside it

```
# cat list_Servicio.json
["Administración de Sistemas"
]
```

When I try to run the job, I got the following message on --comp dropdown

```
Exception: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 47: file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_Administración de Sistemas-componentes.json
URL: file:/scripts/XXXXXXXX/conf/list_Administración de Sistemas-componentes.json
```

[Screenshot with option error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75MBg.png)

I'm using directly ó, without any success.

On bash, it works ok (look at cat above)

Rundeck running with proper encoding

[Screenshot with echo $LANG output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvC7j.png)

PD: linux environment

Any advice?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Did you try with the `ó` character directly? I tested here and works (I'm a native Spanish speaker :D) also, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039464/10426011

Comment: And of course, the main advice is don't use special characters/spaces in folders and files, especially on windows based systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MegaDrive68k Currently, I edited main post to clarify the question. I added some screenshots that help us to addreess it. I ran `echo $LANG` throught rundeck and I got the correct locale (look at 2nd image addedd at main post)

Comment: Did you try with `%20` for spaces? is it possible that your workflow works in a path/file that does not contain spaces? it is good practice not to use spaces or special characters in paths/names. That can generate problems like this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5272